# NewRelic Monitoring Agent Fails on Azure Worker Role

Tags: .net, azure, azure-worker-roles, newrelic

Trying to make NewRelic work with a WorkerRole service. I have followed all instructions properly and encounter this in the NewRelic agent logs:

```
[Info ]Logger initialized.
[Info ]<-- New logging level set.
[Info ]Enabling instrumentation for this process (E:\base\x64\WaWorkerHost.exe) due to it being in a predefined set of processes to be instrumented.
[Info ]Instrumenting method: (Module: D:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll, AppDomain: RdRuntime)[System]System.Net.HttpWebRequest.SerializeHeaders
[Error]Unhandled token encountered while parsing the type.  Token: 0x20
[Error]An exception was thrown while possibly instrumenting function: (Module: D:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\msshrtmi\v4.0_2.1.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\msshrtmi.dll, AppDomain: RdRuntime)[msshrtmi]Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.Internal.InteropLocalResource.GetMaximumSizeInMegaBytes
[Info ]Instrumenting method: (Module: D:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll, AppDomain: RdRuntime)[System]System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse
```

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening? My application isn't reporting and I assume it is because of these unhandled exceptions from NewRelic's monitor.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Without custom instrumentation, Worker Roles only report database calls and external calls. (Instrumenting a Worker Role is similar to [instrumenting a custom application](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/dotnet/instrumenting-custom-applications).) To view other details, you will want to gather custom metrics using the [.NET API](https://newrelic.com/docs/dotnet/the-net-agent-api) and view them in a [custom dashboard](https://newrelic.com/docs/instrumentation/custom-dashboards).

In order for the .NET agent to start up and attach to the application, at least one metric must be collected. If you have an external call or database call that we instrument, then your app will report data to your Applications Overview dashboard. In addition, information about external calls will appear on your app's Map dashboard.

You might try restarting the role if you don't see the app in your New Relic dashboard.  If that doesn't work, remote into the instance and verify that there is a New Relic folder in D:\Program Files.  If you don't find this folder, verify that the following appears in your Worker Role project's ServiceDefinition.csdef file:

`<Task commandLine="newrelic.cmd" executionContext="elevated" taskType="simple">`

Comment: As mentioned in my original post, my configuration is correct and I'm aware of the limitations of the agent. The problem is that the agent outright crashes for one of my Worker Roles, but not for the other, despite having identical configurations.

Comment: In that case, would you please file a support ticket with support@newrelic.com?

Comment: I did you one better and logged an issue with NewRelic's github: https://github.com/newrelic/nuget-azure-cloud-services/issues/18